# emacs flymake error on ubuntu (virtualbox)

Tags: python, ubuntu, emacs, virtualbox, flymake

I'm using emacs 23 on ubuntu 12.04(virtualbox) on windows 7. And i am getting an error like this:

> Flymake:Failed to launch syntax check process 'pyflakes' with args (views_flymake.py): Searching for program: no such file or directory,pyflakes. Flymake will be switched OFF

I couldn't find the solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `pyflakes`. The error says that it is missing.